# Having trouble with defining linear transformation on a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was studying a problem where there was a linear transformation $T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$.We were given that $W$ is finite dimensional. So range$T_2$ is also finite dimensional.So there exists a basis for range$T_2=w_1,...,w_m$ this implies for each $j$, there exists $v_j \in V$ such that $w_j=T_2v_j$.

Because the list of vectors $v_1,...v_m$ is linearly independent in $V$, it can be extended to a basis of $V$.

A  transformation $T_2$can be defined on the whole of $V$

such that $T(a_1v_1+\ldots +a_mv_m)=a_1w_1+\dots +a_mw_m$

Confusion arose for me here because usually we define a transformation on the basis vectors, and $v_1,...,v_m$ is not necessarily a basis for $V$

My question was does this transformation imply all the vectors in the basis but not in the set $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ are mapped into the zero vector?

Somebody replied not necessarily on the previous question I posted.

This reminds me of the problem in an early section:

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional.Prove that any linear map on a subspace of $V$ can be extended to a linear map on $V$.In other words show that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S \in \mathcal{L}(U,W)$ then there exists $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that $Su=Tu$ for all $u \in U$

Proof:Let $u_1,...,u_m$ be a basis for $U$ extend to a basis $u_1,...u_m,v_1,...,v_n$ of $V$.

Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ by $T(u_i)=S(u_i)$ for $i \in \{1,...m\}$ Define $T(v_j)=0$ for $j \in \{1,...,n\}$

Here we are taking all the $v_j's$ equal to zero. And that defines our linear map. Why did this person commenting (about the problem above) state that the other basis vectors of $V$ (not mapped into $w_1,...,w_m$) are not necessarily mapped to the zero vector.This makes me very confused.

Answer (score 1):

If we start with a basis $u_1,\dots,u_m$ of $\textsf U$ and if we extend it to a basis $u_1,\dots,u_m,u_{m+1},\dots,u_n$ of the whole space $\textsf V$, by the theorem that you mentionned above, there exists a unique linear tranformation, $\textsf T$, such that
$$\textsf{T}(u_i) = \begin{cases}
\textsf{S}(u_i) &\textrm{if } 1\leq i\leq m \\
0 &\textrm{if } m+1\leq i\leq n
\end{cases}$$
Now, we claim that $\textsf{T}(v) = \textsf{S}(v)$ for every $v\in\textsf U$. Since any $v\in\textsf U$ can be written as
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^m a_iu_i \quad \textrm{ for some scalars } a_1,\dots,a_m$$
because $u_1,\dots,u_m$ is a basis of $\textsf U$, it follows that
$$\begin{align}
\textsf T(v) &= \textsf T\Big( \sum_{i=1}^m a_iu_i \Big) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m a_i\textsf{T}(u_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m a_i\textsf{S}(u_i) \quad \textrm{ since $i$ is between 1 and $m$} \\
&= \textsf S\Big( \sum_{i=1}^m a_iu_i \Big) = \textsf S(v).
\end{align}$$
As you can observe, that $\textsf{T}(u_i)$ is the zero vector for every $i\in\{m+1,\dots,n\}$ doesn't matter, you can define it in any way.